# Restar filas en R por grupos y por fechas

Tags: r, date, lag

Tengo un data.frame en R, el cual tiene valores acumulados por fechas. Necesito obtener el valor "abolusto" de cada fecha, por lo tanto quiero restarle a cada fecha el valor acumulado de la fecha inmediatamente anterior anterior. Pero tiene otra complejidad, que lo necesito hacer para cada localidad en particular. Tengo una lista donde las localidades se repiten tantas veces haya una fecha con dato, por lo tanto la operación debería hacerse sobre cada localidad en particular y sobre una fecha y la anterior.

```
Fecha        Departamento        Localidad Confirmados Descartados En.estudio Notificaciones
2021-06-10     9 de Julio      ANTONIO PINI           4           2          0              6
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice fue ordenar por fecha primero y luego por localidad

```
base$Fecha = as.Date(base$Fecha)
base %>% arrange(Fecha) %>% arrange(Localidad)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces intente restarle la columna Confirmados, que es la que necesito, a la inmediantamente anterior pero no logró que me de correctamente.

```
df1 <- base %>% mutate(diferencia = Confirmados - lag(Confirmados, 4))
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Hola Mariano, bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Podrías incluir un enlace a los datos o a un ejemplo de los mismos? Quizás el resultado de ' dput(head(base))`. Me parece que un `group_by()` podría resolver tu problema, pero sin los datos es imposible probar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu problema, deseas restar la fecha anterior a los confirmados en base a una agrupación, una posible solución es la siguiente:

Primero creo un data de ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_ejemplo = data.frame(
  localidad = rep(c("Localidad1","Localidad2"),10),
  fechas    = seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-20"),by = 1),
  confirmados = 1:20
)
```

luego aplico el siguiente código:

```
df_ejemplo.1 = df_ejemplo %>%
  arrange(localidad, fechas) %>%
  group_by(localidad) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(diferencia = map(data, function(x) {
    return(c(0, diff(x$confirmados)))
  })) %>%
  unnest(c(data, diferencia))
```

En resumen se hace lo siguiente:

1. Ordenar data frame por localidad y fecha
2. Anidar por localidad, esto creara una lista dentro de tu data frame para cada agrupación,
3. Con la función map a cada lista le aplicamos una función, en este caso, retornamos la diferencia entre confirmados, mediante la función diff , en este punto las fechas estarán ordenadas y las diferencias solo se harán para cada grupo.
4. Desanidar las variables para retornar la data con la nueva variable

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Estás muy cerca de la solución, dos puntos te faltarían:

- Agrupar por localidad
- Hacer que el valor default de `lag` sea cero (para no perder el primer caso)

---

```
df %>% 
  arrange(localidad, fecha) %>% 
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  mutate(diferencia = confirmados - lag(confirmados, default = 0))
```